# Angular2: Unable to emit data to other component. Backend service being called Twice

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-event-emitter

I have a requirement where `ngOnInit`, I am extracting the query params from URL, preparing a url for making backend `api` call something like `http://localhost:8080/myapp/video0=5&video1=6` and emitting the data received to be used in other component.

Now, when I look into browser console and network tabs, I see two calls to my backend api: one without parameters and one with paramters. Obviously, one with parameters fetches me desired data. This `data` is required in another component for further processing.

Here is how `ngOnInit` looks like in one component:

```
ngOnInit() {

this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
     this.video0 = params['video0'];
     this.video1 = params['video1'];
     this.video2 = params['video2'];
     this.video3 = params['video3'];

    this.sharedRequestPath = this.prepareSharedLinkRequestPath(this.video0,this.video1,this.video2,this.video3);  // creates a url for fetching data.

   this.getSharedVideosData(this.sharedRequestPath);  //this makes the backend call.

    this.addVideosEvent.emit(this.sharedVideos); //finally emitting the data populated in variable

 });
}
```

The part to fetch data from backend: `getSharedVideoData`

```
 getSharedVideosData(requestPath) {

  this.modelService.getVideos(requestPath).subscribe(
      data => {
      this.videoData = data;

            for (let j = 0; j < this.videoData.length; j++) {
                          this.sharedVideos[j] = this.videoData[j];
            }
      });  
   }
```

`getVideos` method in `modelService` is:

```
getVideos(videoDataQuery): Observable < MyObj[] > {
    return this.http.get(videoDataQuery).map((response: Response) => {
        return <MyObj[]> response.json()
    }).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And finally, the emitter event on another component:

```
 <app-form (addVideosEvent)="addVideos($event)" ></app-form>
```

`addVideos` method is used for further processing of data which contains alert statement. As the page loads, I see two alert statements but both without any data.

This is strange because browser network tabs shows me the response but it is not emitted properly i guess. Am I doing it the correct way?

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just subscribe that emitted data in Component and put it where you want.

```
this.addVideosEvent.subscribe(yourEmittedData=>{
       console.log( 'emittedData' , yourEmittedData )
)
```

Comment: In which component I have to subscribe?

Comment: If your emiting in componentA then you have to subscribe it in componentA only @roger_that

Answer (score 0):

- The correct syntax for **component** subscribe is =>

  ```
  this.addVideosEvent.subscribe(yourEmittedData=>{
      console.log( 'emittedData' , yourEmittedData )
  })
  ```
- The correct syntax for **service** subscribe is =>

  ```
   myFunction(callback:(data:any)=>void){
      this.addVideosEvent.subscribe((yourEmittedData:any)=>{
         console.log( 'emittedData' , yourEmittedData )
         callback(yourEmittedData);
      })
   })
  ```

Comment: I guess you didn't understand the question. I want to use the data in another component